# HTML5 Canvas realtime collaboration whiteboard draw line not draw properly when canvas size is diffrent

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, canvas, html5-canvas

I m working on an HTML5 Canvas realtime collaboration whiteboard which is built-in below technology

- Front End:  HTML5 Canvas, Angular 9 , TypeScript
- For Drawing Signal : Azure SignalR

In this application when we draw any object on one whiteboard it will be visible to another user also another user draw anything can see my other users For example: https://app.ziteboard.com/

**Main Issue:**

When the user draws the line on the canvas at that time we are sending start position(x,y) and next position(x,y) to another users canvas to draw the same design its working proper is canvas height and width is same but if it's not same then it does not show the same line

***Note: Canvas resize based on screen**

**Drawing line Code**

```
  fromEvent(canvasEl, 'mousedown')
        .pipe(
            switchMap((e) => {
                e.preventDefault();
                // after a mouse down, we'll record all mouse moves
                return fromEvent(canvasEl, 'mousemove')
                    .pipe(
                        // we'll stop (and unsubscribe) once the user releases the mouse
                        // this will trigger a 'mouseup' event    
                        takeUntil(fromEvent(canvasEl, 'mouseup')),
                        // we'll also stop (and unsubscribe) once the mouse leaves the canvas (mouseleave event)
                        takeUntil(fromEvent(canvasEl, 'mouseleave')),
                        // pairwise lets us get the previous value to draw a line from
                        // the previous point to the current point    
                        pairwise()
                    )
            })
        )
        .subscribe((res: [MouseEvent, MouseEvent]) => {
            const rect = canvasEl.getBoundingClientRect();
            const prevPos = {
                x: res[0].clientX - rect.left,
                y: res[0].clientY - rect.top
            };

            const currentPos = {
                x: res[1].clientX - rect.left,
                y: res[1].clientY - rect.top
            };

            // this method we'll implement soon to do the actual drawing
            this.drawOnCanvas(prevPos, currentPos);

            this.sendDrawSignals(prevPos.x, prevPos.y, currentPos.x, currentPos.y);
        });
}
```

**Draw function based on the position**

```
private drawOnCanvas(prevPos: { x: number, y: number }, currentPos: { x: number, y: number }) {
        if (!this.cx) { return; }
        this.cx.beginPath();

        if (prevPos) {
            this.cx.moveTo(prevPos.x, prevPos.y); // from
            this.cx.lineTo(currentPos.x, currentPos.y);
            this.cx.stroke();
        }
    }
```

**Send Drawling signal Function to another user**

```
**sendDrawSignals(prevPosX: number, prevPosY: number, currentPosX: number, currentPosY: number) {
          const prevPositon: PointerPosition = {
             x: prevPosX,
             y: prevPosY
            }
            const currentPositon: PointerPosition = {
                x: currentPosX,
                y: currentPosY
            }
        var clientAccountEl = document.getElementById('canvas-accountid');
        let clientAccountId: number = +clientAccountEl.getAttribute("value");
        var coachAccountEl = document.getElementById('canvas-coachaccountid');
        let coachtAccountId: number = +coachAccountEl.getAttribute("value");
            const drawPositions: DrawPositions = {
                accountId: clientAccountId,
                coachAccountId: coachtAccountId,
                directSessionId: this.directSessionId,
                currentPos: currentPositon,
                prevPos: prevPositon
             }
        this.notificationHub.invoke('drawPositions', this.notificationHub.connectionId, drawPositions);
    }**
```

**Receive signals to draw**

```
this.notificationHub.on('drawPositions', async data => {
            if (data) {
                let drawPositions: DrawPositions = data;
                if (drawPositions.directSessionId == this.directSessionId) {
                    this.drawOnCanvas(drawPositions.prevPos, drawPositions.currentPos);
                }
            }
        });
```

**Canvas Resize code**

```
 const canvasEl: HTMLCanvasElement = this.canvas.nativeElement;
        this.cx = canvasEl.getContext('2d');

        canvasEl.width = canvasEl.parentElement.offsetWidth;
        canvasEl.height = canvasEl.parentElement.offsetHeight;
```

Images of Problem

[Mobile View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5qwZ.png)

[Desktop View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BqcR.png)

**Drawing drawn on the desktop not show on on mobile**

[Mobile Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWeFX.png)
[Desktop view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kX4a.png)

Comment: Well from these screenshots, the lines look identical to me: https://jsfiddle.net/ecb8v20x/

Comment: @Kaiido I need to show this line as per screen size currently as we take a pointer from a mobile device which is not drawn properly on desktop view as you can see in  images

Comment: I don't understand... The lines are exactly the same in both ends, what's the issue? To help you, a bit, forget about the screen size and mouse coordinates. Think of your drawing app as an infinite plane, where all your users will be able to navigate using their own camera. That doesn't matter where it is rendered on their screen, as long as there is a constant "world" coordinate system. One user can zoom in a particular point to draw something, that something should appear small to an other user that zoomed out to see the whole picture.

Comment: I want to show a full portion of a desktop drawing in mobile view  please check latest images

Comment: You need to add controls on your app so that your users can navigate through this infinite plane 'world' I was talking about. The app you linked to has this option on the right side. There is nothing wrong with your code, you need to review your app's design.